# Select columns and lines with condition from file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a program that opens a text file with only numbers in rows and columns, to save them in a new file. The part where I select columns works, while the part of the rows don't. I must select the lines with the condition x > 10e13 (where x is the value in a specific column).
I have some problems, especially in rows selection.
Since they are very large files, I have been advised to use numpy, so I would like to run the code this way. 
This is the code I have written:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt('file.dat') 

#select columns
column_indicies = [0] 
selected_columns = matrix[:,column_indicies]

x=1E14    #select lines
for line in matrix:
   if float(line) > x:
      #any ideas?

selected_matrix = matrix[selected_lines,selected_columns]

np.savetxt('new_file.dat', selected_matrix, fmt='%1.4f')
```

This is a small sample of my input data:

```
185100000000000.0000
121300000000000.0000
257800000000000.0000
43980000000000.0000
```

Comment: You need to select any element larger than x or any row? Don't fully understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here is what you might want to try which is along the same direction you have already taken:

```
matrix = <your matrix>
new_matrix = np.array([]).reshape(matrix.shape)
column_index = <the column index you want to compare>
x = 1E14
for line in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    if matrix[line][column_index] > x:
         new_matrix.append(matrix[line])
```

Hope that makes sense. We are attaching only those rows to the new matrix that meets your condition. I didn't run the code, so there might be some minor bugs. But, I am hoping you got the idea of how you can accomplish this task.